# Recovery my data in hard disk

Tags: data-recovery

At that time of installing Ubuntu 16.04 in my laptop. Its deleted my entire data in my hard disk.
whether its possible to recover my file Ubuntu os.
If yes kindly provide me solution.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! How was the original data stored? NTFS? EXT4? Another file system? What was the partition layout before the fact? What is the partition layout now? We are missing **a lot** of details.

Answer (score 0):

There are some third-party software out there you help get your data back, because when a file is deleted, that space is marked "empty" but not actually deleted. To fully delete it you must overwrite that space. However beware that some files could be corrupt.